# OpenCV object detect algorithm freezes after training cascade

Tags: c++, opencv, object-detection, haar-classifier

I trained the cascade classifier to detect letters, [this](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/objectDetection/objectDetection.cpp) is the code I'm using.

When I start the program, it opens my web cam but doesn't show the image (frames) and the detection but just a single blank window.

I noticed this line causes the problem:

```
faces_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, faces, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));
```

[This](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxebgapvybQueDZRM3BsdW50d0k/view) is the xml file.

What should I do to make it show the captured frames and start detecting?

Thank you.

Comment: This code works fine for me.  What is the exact behavior you're experiencing?  Does the window just stay blank until you hit <escape> to exit the program?

Comment: Thank you for helping, the window stays blank and doesn't pop up another window to show the frames and detection (imshow())

Comment: Have you been able to display any images successfully using `imshow`?

Comment: yes I did, this code: https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/blob/master/samples/cpp/tutorial_code/objectDetection/objectDetection.cpp worked great for me

Comment: Maybe there could be a problem n the .xml file because only when I change it the program stops working. Please take a look in this link for the files I used: https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxebgapvybQuRzJCTFgtQ2VjYnM Is there anything you can suggest me to make it work?

Comment: It doesn't look to me like the .xml file should influence the basic rendering of the image.  One thing I did notice is that the tutorial code you provided the link to uses `capture.open(-1)`, whereas you're using `capture.open(0)`.  Is it possible you're actually activating a different camera device (for example, an integrated laptop camera instead of your webcam)?  If so, maybe the other camera is not initializing properly, defaulting to an exposure/brightness level that's far too low, or even maybe it's just physically blocked by your actual webcam.

Comment: I changed it back, but unfortunately it still doesn't work. Could it be that the .xml file is too short? I train the cascade only with 15 positive images because I want the cascade to recognize letters.

Comment: if you remove ellipse drawing, does it display the original image?

Comment: No, only if I remove the detectMultiScale

Comment: letter_cascade.detectMultiScale(frame_gray, letters, 1.1, 2, 0 | CASCADE_SCALE_IMAGE, Size(30, 30));

Comment: My .xml file size is only 4 kb, could it be the problem?

Comment: can you try `detectAndDisplay(frame.clone());`? Afaik VideoCapture already copies the image, but just in case that the framebuffer is overwritten during detectMultiscale (it takes some time) you could try it.

Comment: does it work if you load one of the with-opencv-delivered cascade classifiers instead of your one?

Comment: Yes, it works with other opencv cascade classifiers, I noticed if I change the capture.open(0);  to  (-1), after I pick up the desired device the program automatically closes

Comment: Anyone has any suggestion - my webcam only opens but doesn't respond to  imshow(window_name, frame);

Answer (score 0):

I finally got it, I had to train my cascade with the parameters of: -w 24 -h 24 to specify a rectangular image which I have used.
Now the code runs normally.