# OpenCV cascade classifier training - 1-stage stops

Tags: opencv, object-detection

I try to train the cascade using the following parameters:

```
 C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\opencv_traincascade.exe -data C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\tl_train -vec C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\tl_train_samples.vec -bg C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\tl_neg.dat -numPos 70 -numNeg 900 -numStages 10 -minHitRate 0.1 -w 40 -h 40 -featureType LBP -precalcValBufSize 1024 -precalcldxBufSize 1024
```

The result I get is:

```
PARAMETERS:
cascadeDirName: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\tl_train
vecFileName: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\tl_train_samples.vec
bgFileName: C:\opencv\build\x86\vc12\bin\tl_neg.dat
numPos: 70
numNeg: 900
numStages: 10
precalcValBufSize[Mb] : 1024
precalcIdxBufSize[Mb] : 1024
acceptanceRatioBreakValue : -1
stageType: BOOST
featureType: LBP
sampleWidth: 40
sampleHeight: 40
boostType: GAB
minHitRate: 0.999
maxFalseAlarmRate: 0.5
weightTrimRate: 0.95
maxDepth: 1
maxWeakCount: 100
Number of unique features given windowSize [40,40] : 67600

===== TRAINING 0-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   70 : 70
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    900 : 1
Precalculation time: 2.512
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1| 0.213333|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 6 seconds.

===== TRAINING 1-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   70 : 70
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    900 : 0.214184
Precalculation time: 2.461
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   3|        1| 0.201111|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 13 seconds.

===== TRAINING 2-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   70 : 70
NEG count : acceptanceRatio    900 : 0.043021
Precalculation time: 2.588
+----+---------+---------+
|  N |    HR   |    FA   |
+----+---------+---------+
|   1|        1|        1|
+----+---------+---------+
|   2|        1|        0|
+----+---------+---------+
END>
Training until now has taken 0 days 0 hours 0 minutes 22 seconds.

===== TRAINING 3-stage =====
<BEGIN
POS count : consumed   70 : 70
Train dataset for temp stage can not be filled. Branch training terminated.
```

The real number of positive examples is 91 and the negative is 1046.

What should I do to make the program run trough all the stages specified in the parameters?

Thank you.

Comment: how many negative samples do you have?

Comment: for your information: if numNeg is 160 you need 160 negatives in each stage. In your first stage you have hit rate of 100% and false alarms 0% which means that all 160 negatives of the first stage are consumed and not usable for future stages anymore

Comment: Thank you for answering, I changed the parameters above and got a new problem (I also changed the negative and positive examples so there are more than before)

Comment: how many positives do you have? In each stage, the number of positive samples reduces by the "missed" positive samples. In your example, you use 70 positives in each stage and a hitrate of 44.3% in stage 0. That means for example if you had let's say 90 positives in your vec-file then in stage 1 there are left only `(90-70*(1-0.443)) = 39` usable positives. You should try the following: increase minHitRate ( >= 0.9 I would suggest 0.995 or 0.999 in the first tries), increase the number of positive samples and/or maybe decrease numPos.

Comment: from a comment in http://answers.opencv.org/question/776/error-in-parameter-of-traincascade/ : `vec-file has to contain >= (numPose + (numStages-1) * (1 - minHitRate) * numPose) + S`

Comment: I did what you suggested but now I get a different error, what could cause that one?

Comment: I would guess that there are no negatives left. How many do you have?

Comment: and/or a syntax error in your negatives-file. The error is the same you had some days ago, right? Where there were wrong reltive pathes in the file?

Comment: I think you're right, I added more negatives so I have now 1,087 and I managed to proceed to one more stage in training

Comment: But I still have the problem that when I load the cascade I trained, the program does't work - it shows only a blank window as I described here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37943723/opencv-2-4-13-object-detect-code-doesnt-work-after-training-cascade?noredirect=1#comment63346805_37943723 do you have any suggestions?